# rosdep is not working in my ubuntu 11.10

Tags: rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Tutorial link: http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage

while I run

rospack depends1 beginner_tutorials

I got the following error

ImportError: No module named rospack
ImportError: No module named rospack
[rospack] Error: could not find python module 'rosdep2.rospack'. is rosdep up-to-date (at least 0.10.4)?

How can I tackle this problem

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57427/rosdep-is-not-working-in-my-ubuntu-11.10/) by [unais](https://answers.ros.org/users/4285/unais/) on ROS Answers with karma: 313 on 2013-03-07

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-03-07**:
Can you check `rosdep --version` and `which rosdep`?

**Comment by [unais](https://answers.ros.org/users/4285/unais/) on 2013-03-07**:
rosdep version is  -    0.9.3
which rosdep:  - /usr/local/bin/rosdep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have an old rosdep installed.

Uninstall/Remove the rosdep version in /usr/local/bin and
install the package python-rosdep.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [unais](https://answers.ros.org/users/4285/unais/) on 2013-03-07**:
How can I  done this?

**Comment by [unais](https://answers.ros.org/users/4285/unais/) on 2013-03-07**:
How can I remove my older rosdep package?

**Comment by [unais](https://answers.ros.org/users/4285/unais/) on 2013-03-07**:
Thank you ! I recovered the problem .. Now Its working fine

**Comment by [Asfandyar Ashraf Malik](https://answers.ros.org/users/5044/asfandyar-ashraf-malik/) on 2014-04-20**:
@unais How did you fix this. How did you remove it and then installed the new one

**Comment by [Asfandyar Ashraf Malik](https://answers.ros.org/users/5044/asfandyar-ashraf-malik/) on 2014-04-21**:
@dornhege I am encountering the same problem. I have removed rosdep from /usr/local/bin and reinstalled via "sudo apt-get install python-rosdep" but still I am encountering the same problem